# Cowboy server exits on start without errors

Tags: elixir, cowboy

I'm running a simple cowboy server. Here's my application file:

```
defmodule MyApp.Application do                                                      
  @moduledoc "Application file"                                                    
                                                                                   
  use Application                                                                  
                                                                                   
  def start(_type, _args) do                                                       
    children = [                                                                   
      Plug.Cowboy.child_spec(                                                      
        scheme: :http,                                                             
        plug: MyApp.Web.Endpoint,                                                   
        options: [port: 8000]                                                                                                                                          
      )                                                                            
    ]                                                                              
                                                                                   
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]                         
    IO.puts("Starting...")                                                         
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts) |> IO.inspect                            
  end                                                                              
end
```

And here is my endpoint:

```
defmodule MyApp.Web.Endpoint do                                                     
  @moduledoc """                                                                   
  This is the module responsible for processing incoming requests                  
  """                                                                              
                                                                                   
  use Plug.Router                                                                  
  import Plug.Conn, only: [send_resp: 3]                                           
                                                                                   
  plug(Plug.Logger)                                                                
  plug(:match)                                                                     
  plug(:dispatch)                                                                  
                                                                                   
  get "/ping" do                                                                   
    send_resp(conn, 200, "pong")                                                                                                                                       
  end                                                                              
                                                                                   
end
```

After running `mix run`, I see the start up log ("Starting..."), but my app exits immediately instead of listening for connections. How do I keep it listening indefinitely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [mix run docs](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Run.html):

> `mix run` can be used to start the current application dependencies, the
> application itself, and optionally run some code in its context. For
> long running systems, this is typically done with the `--no-halt`
> option:
>
> ```
> mix run --no-halt
> ```